Jenkins does not start anymore after plugin update
I have 2.479.1 LTS installed on a Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-126-generic x86_64).
After a plugin upgrade, jenkins refuses to start.
When I try manually:
buildmaster@jenkins$~: sudo systemctl start jenkins.service
[sudo] password for buildmaster:
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xeu jenkins.service" for details.

journalctl -xeu jenkins.service reveals:
Nov 19 14:10:44 jenkins jenkins[9661]: Error: Could not find or load main class self
Nov 19 14:10:44 jenkins jenkins[9661]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: self
Nov 19 14:10:44 jenkins systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

I have no clue, what can I do?
When I simply start jenkins with /usr/bin/jenkins then it uses wrong jenkins home, even if I set variable JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins before. But its the wrong user anyway.
How can I get it to run again?

Btw.
buildmaster@jenkins:~$ java --version
java 17.0.12 2024-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286, mixed mode, sharing)

Isn't /usr/bin/jenkins a wrapper shell script, which is setting the ENV JENKINS_HOME overwriting the env var? Try to edit /usr/bin/jenkins and edit the var there.
